# Getting groups from a Child domain in Active Directory

Tags: security, active-directory, c++

I'm writing a C++ way of getting users and groups of Active Directory.
This implementation was finished, but now I'm adding support for multiple domains.

The setup where I test this is as follows.

I have one domain (lets call it A), with one child domain (B).
I am by default connected to this parent domain domain A.

When I connect to domain B in my implementation and fetch all groups for this domain, it gives me all groups from B AND from A.
This is (from a security standpoint) not something I expect.

Is this because my default domain as user is A?

Comment: Probably need to see the code or you need to redo the logic for each explicit domain with for example the actual domain names. Maybe with the way your logic is setup now, it just gets all domains that are available which it can ready from--hard telling without seeing your C++ logic though.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill My question is more related to how Active Directory handles child domains, and not to my implementation. I can move it to SO if you want, but since it is not programming related in my opinion it does not belong there.

Comment: @MagicallyDelicous What I do: setup connection to the domain, check if everything went well. Fetch all the groups within this domain, and store them. This method is used for every domain, and every connection is created and closed after the iteration. There is no "sharing" in place, hence my surprise when seeing the groups from domain A.

Comment: @SimonHoubracken I wasn't completely sure where the best place was, so I didn't actually vote to migrate. It was more to point out to you that it might be related to your code and the way you are using the API calls (as per the comment above by Magically).

Comment: Simon - Can you show the logic that is used for (or built to) call the domain(s)? That'd give me a better idea of what protocol you're using and the commands i.e. LDAP, etc.